# Custom dimension not working with gtag.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, gtag.js

I can't send custom dimension data to Google Analytics.
I followed [this google instructions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets) adapted to my needs, but it doesn't work. I added the dimensions in Analytics, but it seems that there's no data about these custom dimensions.

[This](https://www.travelemiliaromagna.it/campionato-europeo-under-21-in-emilia-romagna/) is an example page of the website where this happens

And here you can find the code i'm using on that page

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
var author = 'Walter Manni';
var year = '2019';
var prov = '';
var dest = '';
gtag('js', new Date());
// Configures custom dimension<Index> to use the custom parameter
// 'dimension_name' for 'GA_TRACKING_ID', where <Index> is a number
// representing the index of the custom dimension.
gtag('config', 'xxxxxxxx',{
    'anonymize_ip': true,
    'custom_map': {
        'dimension1': 'author',
        'dimension2': 'year',
        'dimension3': 'provincia',
        'dimension4': 'destinazione',
    }
}
);
gtag('event', 'author_dimension', {
    'author': author
});
gtag('event', 'year_dimension', {
    'year': year
});
```

Thank you for your help!